# How to query ledger and historic data in Hyper-ledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

As ledger contains a sequence of transaction, How can I query the current state of ledger and Historic data from ledger.

Answer (score 4):

If you interested in history data in context of the chaincode, you could use `ChaincodeStubInterface` API, e.g.

```
// GetHistoryForKey returns a history of key values across time.
// For each historic key update, the historic value and associated
// transaction id and timestamp are returned. The timestamp is the
// timestamp provided by the client in the proposal header.
// GetHistoryForKey requires peer configuration
// core.ledger.history.enableHistoryDatabase to be true.
// The query is NOT re-executed during validation phase, phantom reads are
// not detected. That is, other committed transactions may have updated
// the key concurrently, impacting the result set, and this would not be
// detected at validation/commit time. Applications susceptible to this
// should therefore not use GetHistoryForKey as part of transactions that
// update ledger, and should limit use to read-only chaincode operations.
GetHistoryForKey(key string) (HistoryQueryIteratorInterface, error)
```

which is capable to retrieve entire history for given key, you receiving back iterator, which will provide you insight on historical changes of the the given key, for example:

```
historyIer, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(yourKeyIsHere)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(errMsg)
    return shim.Error(errMsg)
}

if historyIer.HasNext() {
    modification, err := historyIer.Next()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(errMsg)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }
    fmt.Println("Returning information about", string(modification.Value))
}
```

Also note, that you need to make sure history db is enabled, in `core.yaml` file part of the ledger section:

```
ledger:

  history:
    # enableHistoryDatabase - options are true or false
    # Indicates if the history of key updates should be stored.
    # All history 'index' will be stored in goleveldb, regardless if using
    # CouchDB or alternate database for the state.
    enableHistoryDatabase: true
```

Comment: @ Hi Artem: can we query ledger based on transaction Id.

Comment: There is no way with shim API to query ledger for txID, while at applicatin level, you can do it with SDK, see example here: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryTransaction

Comment: Hi, I wonder if the historyDB is used to store the modification history of a key? Is that correct?

Comment: @Wandy yes, it is.

Comment: @ArtemBarger where does GetHistoryForKey pull data from? since World State does not store history data is it directly fetched from the blockchain?

Comment: From history database

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/core/scc/qscc) to query the ledger.
It's a system chaincode that is used to query the peer.
It has all kinds of queries such as get block by number, etc.